# Why is the Fogbugz API not allowing me to logon?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I can't seem to logon to the FogBugz v8 API with my credentials. Our system is setup to use Active Directory.

Does it not allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this one out!

When calling the API *YOU MUST URL ENCODE ALL THE URL PARAMETERS!!*

In my case I wasn't encoding the username (my email) and password (lots of goofy characters)

**ONE MORE NOTE:** You must URL Encode the API Token as well.